# SQL Server 2008 Update Trigger - Updating certain column approach

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, triggers

I'm creating a trigger on one table which should update `date_modified` column. Is below code the best approach to do this? Am I doing this right?

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM DELETED) --checking if this is an update, not insert
BEGIN
IF NOT(UPDATE(date_modified)) -- checking if desired column was not updated
BEGIN
    DECLARE @updatedID int
    SELECT @updatedID = ID FROM deleted -- fetching updated record ID
    UPDATE table SET date_modified=GETDATE() WHERE ID=@updatedID -- updating desired column
END
```

Comment: Sorry, updated platform data into post and topic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use this instead of declaring variable

```
UPDATE table SET date_modified=GETDATE() WHERE ID in 
(SELECT ID FROM deleted)
```